# Phonegap App distrubute versions for tablet OR smartphone Android

Tags: eclipse, cordova, tablet, smartphone

Hey i want to have a tablet version and a smartphone version of my app, made with phonegap. How can i realize this (in Android). Can i check if it is a tablet or smartphone with javascript? I don´t think it works properly. Or can i set it in the manifest for example and upload 2 APK to the play store?

please help me

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a purely JS solution, you could look at the screen size, something like this:

```
MIN_TABLET_SCREEN_WIDTH = 720;
IS_TABLET = Math.min($(window).width(), $(window).height()) >= MIN_TABLET_SCREEN_WIDTH;
IS_PHONE = !IS_TABLET;
```

One man's small tablet is another man's large phone - it depends how big your hands are :-)
So you can tweak the value of MIN_TABLET_SCREEN_WIDTH to determine what screen size is appropriate for your purposes to distinguish as a tablet or a phone.

Comment: yeah but a tablet can have the same screensize (in px) like a newer smartphone, thats the problem...

Comment: For my purposes, screensize is enough: if there's enough pixels to display my tablet view (even if every pixel is smaller because it's really a high res phone display), that suits my needs. But if you need to distinguish based on some other criteria such as physical screen size, then you'll need to do something based on the physical device, such as use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)